# How to expose JMXConfigurator logback operations in Restful Webservices?

Tags: rest, log4j, logback, slf4j, jmx

I need to change different log levels in runtime and I want to control the log levels changes by using restful webservices, but I got struck how to achieve this .
can any of you help me on this?

From the below Image from Jconsole you can see log back operations like setLoggerLevel & getLoggerLevels. 
[image: JMX Configurator-JConsole]

I need to expose these operations via Restful Webservices instead of accessing it from Jconsole.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://jolokia.org.
It exposes the JVM's JMX services via REST.